# JSON server get resources

Tags: javascript, json, json-server

I'm trying to build fast back-end using [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server)

My endpoint and data like this:

Endpoint: `http://localhost:3000/members/1`

Output data:

[image]

Now let's say I wanna do several things like:

1. Get all reports of a member.

Following by docs and I was tried to do:
`http://localhost:3000/members/1?_embed=reports` to get `reports` array. 
But it's response me empty array:

```
{
id: 1,
username: "member1",
firstName: "Miss Osbaldo",
lastName: "Wisozk",
password: "123456",
role: "member",
reports: [ ]
}
```

2. I want to add some `report` Object to `reports` array. 
   How can I do that?

For example member with `id=1` create a new report. And after that report should exist in `reports` array of member 1.

My `generates.js` file:

```
return {
members: _.times(30, function (n) {
  return {
    id: (n + 1),
    username: 'member' + (n + 1),
    firstName: faker.name.prefix() + ' ' + faker.name.firstName(),
    lastName: faker.name.lastName(),
    avatar: faker.image.avatar(),
    address: faker.address.streetAddress("###") + ' ' + faker.address.city() + ' ' + faker.address.county(),
    phone: faker.phone.phoneNumberFormat(),
    division: faker.random.arrayElement(division),
    password: "123456",
    role: "member",
    reports: _.times(5, function (n) {
      return {
        id: n,
        date: faker.date.weekday(),
        achievement: faker.lorem.sentence(),
        issues: faker.random.arrayElement(issues),
        descriptions: faker.lorem.paragraphs(),
        comment: faker.lorem.sentences()
      }
    })
  }
}),
```

Comment: How do you access that reports array or the api will automatically returns an array?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I'm using `faker`, `lodash` and create generate file. I was updated above.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#relationships) and the [live demo](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com) your first request/query is correct: `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1?_embed=comments` returns post #1 plus all its comments.

For your question #1, I'd recommend double checking your database file.

For your second question, you can use HTTP verbs like POST and PATCH: https://github.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder#updating-a-resource
this should update your "database" file (json file)

Comment: What is double checking does? I just only want to get `reports` array.

Comment: Sorry, I mean just make sure the json file that the server is using as its "database" has the data you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

For your question #1 use `http://localhost:3000/members/1/reports` route. It'll return all reports of member #1

Answer (score 0):

db = {}

```
db.posts = [
  { id: 1, body: 'foo' },
  { id: 2, body: 'bar' },
]

db.comments = [
  { id: 1, post_id: 1 },
  { id: 2, post_id: 1 },
  { id: 3, post_id: 2 },
]

server = jsonServer.create()
router = jsonServer.router(db, { foreignKeySuffix: '_id' })
server.use(jsonServer.defaults())
server.use(router)
```

})